# Incorrect credentials when trying to clone Repository to NetBeans with https

Tags: git, github, netbeans, repository

I use NetBeans 12.5, set up a new projek and want to clone an existing repository to my local drive. I use Tools -> Git -> Clone... [image of top meny choices made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNiki.png)

After entering the Repository URL and a user /password i get the error message: Incorrect credentials for repository at https://github.com/MYORG/PATH/TO/myrepro
[Image of Clone-Repoitiry wizzard window and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgXn.png)

I have checked that I can login tp the repository on Github with exactly that combination of usernamn and password that that worked.

I have also used the comandline interface to clone my repository and that worked (to make sure it's not a connectivity issue). The comandline that I use is exaclty the same path to repro and it clones the correct repository:
git clone https://github.com/MYORG/PATH/TO/myrepro

However the comandline uses a differnet authenticator (info: please complete authentication in your browser...).

My question is:
1)How can I get the NetBeans clone to work.
2)As a workaround, can I clone by comandline and to which diretory do I have to clone?

Answer (score 22):

follow these steps to solve it :

1. login to your github account and click on your username and select
   settings
2. on the sidebar select "developper settings"
3. select on the shown screen "personal access tokens
4. on top right select "generate new token"
5. under "note" field give a name to the generated tokens
6. give an expiration to your token under "expiration" field
7. under "select scope" check "repo"
8. click "generate token"
9. copy the generated token and save it anywhere safely and use it on
   netbeans as password

Comment: This is the solution where i searched for several times in the last year.